# sign in/ Login Via twitter iOS7

Tags: objective-c, parsing, twitter, ios7

it has been two weeks and I couldn't find a useful answer for my query, I've tried a lot of codes nothing had worked for me, Actually i am trying to build a log in page that able to user to sign in/log in from their Facebook or Twitter, its totally work for Facebook but the problem with twitter.

I've tried this code below please advice and help as I am still getting an error and the error is

(property twitterHandle not found on object of type "ViewController")

here is the code I've used.Note that I use **Parse** for my database.

*I've created an action button in the header called Twitter

```
-(IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender;
```

*and I had this code in the m file as showing below:

```
- (IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender {
{
    // borrowed from: http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2012/04/18/using-twitter-ios5-integration-single-sign-on/
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if(granted) {
            // Access has been granted, now we can access the accounts
            // Remember that twitterType was instantiated above
            NSArray *twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];

            // If there are no accounts, we need to pop up an alert
            if(twitterAccounts != nil && [twitterAccounts count] == 0)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Twitter Accounts"
                                                                message:@"There are no Twitter accounts configured. You must add or create a Twitter separately."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            } else {
                ACAccount *account = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                // Do something with their Twitter account
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
                SLRequest *req = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                              URL:url
                                                       parameters:nil];
                // Important: attach the user's Twitter ACAccount object to the request
                req.account = account;
                [req performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                                 NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                                 NSError *error)
                {
                    // If there was an error making the request, display a message to the user
                    if(error != nil) {
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter Error"
                                                                        message:@"There was an error talking to Twitter. Please try again later."
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];
                        return;
                    }
                    // Parse the JSON response
                    NSError *jsonError = nil;
                    id resp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&jsonError];
                    // If there was an error decoding the JSON, display a message to the user
                    if(jsonError != nil)
                    {
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter Error"
                                                                        message:@"Twitter is not acting properly right now. Please try again later."
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];
                        return;
                    }

                    NSString *screenName = [resp objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
                    self.twitterHandle = screenName;
                    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
                    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
                    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:currentUser.username];
                    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            // Do something with the found objects
                            for (PFObject *object in objects)
                            {
                                object[@"TwitterHandle"] = self.twitterHandle;
                                [object saveInBackground];
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Log details of the failure
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                        }
                    }];
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
    }
```

Please Please Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(property twitterHandle not found on object of type "ViewController")
```

is telling you that somewhere, you are trying to access a property called `twitterHandle` on an object of type `ViewController` which has no such property.

I suspect the issue is in this line:

```
self.twitterHandle = screenName;
```

You just need to add a property to your view controller interface like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *twitterHandle;
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the run time  **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController TwitterButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Comment: Hi! If your first question was answered, mark the answer and create a new question if you have a new one.